# Returning values from a service class in bean-getters: Does it hurt readability and is it "clean code"?

Tags: java, jsf

Im currently working on homework for my programming class. We work with JSF (but this is a question that can be generally applied to java) and I was wondering if this is good practise:

In the first step of the homework I was supposed to add a List of products to the bean. At this point it looks like this:

```
public class PricelistBean {
    private List<Product> productList;


    public PricelistBean(){
        this.productList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.productList.add(new Product(1001, "electric toothbrush", 23.0f));
        this.productList.add(new Product(1002, "toy boat large", 50.4f));
        this.productList.add(new Product(1003, "dyson vacuum cleaner", 299.0f));
    }
    public List<Product> getProductList() {
        return this.productList;
    }

    public void setProductList(List<Product> productList) {
        this.productList = productList;
    }
}
```

The next step was to move this to a service class. Now my idea was to simply remove the product list and move it to the service class and then reuse the get and sets and have it modify/return the list in the service class like so:

```
public List<Product> getProductList(){ return this.productListService.getProductList(); };
public void setProductList(List<Product> productList){this.productlistService.setProductList(productList); } ;
```

This would allow me to have to change absolutely nothing in my actual facelet (view). However, I dont know if this is considered good practice and if this hurts readability (since id assume that someone reading this would just assume that there is a property in the bean from reading the values in the view and then get confused). I dont want to teach myself a bad coding style.

NOTE: When I say "style" I mean that I want to follow generally accepted coding principles to get a coding style that is pretty universally accepted as "decent". I know the subject is not objective, however I think its not off topic if we limit it to universally accepted clean code principles.

Comment: If your code is working then maybe this question would be a better fit for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Getters and setters are generally bad. You are treating your classes as generic bags of data. Classes should encapsulate state and provide behaviour. How is it better than a normal `List<Product>`, except that it adds a few items by default?

Comment: @Michael I dont understand your point? If you are talking about a service class its just a singelton that is supposed to provide methods and functions that allow the upper layer of the app to work together easily. I dont understand what your point is sorry :/

Comment: @Lino Oh! I think you are right... I will post my next question like this on codereview

Comment: My point is give the view a `List<Product>`. There is no value in `PricelistBean`.

Comment: @Michael In jsf beans are the "backend" of a view. The views themselves are just xhtml files that are parsed into a component tree by jsf. Having them in the bean is "giving the view a List<Product>". As for the service class, imo its good to have the "main" data in a central singelton since it might be modified by multiple sources, but I am happy to hear your opinion on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping data separate from presentation /view (facelet) is a good practice. This way you can decouple your presentation from data or any processing on data.

Another advantage is you can share the state of the bean if data is present in the bean. You can make it immutable or singleton also based on your requirement.